# What happens when one of the name servers cannot resolve a host?

Tags: domain-name-system

Let's say I assigned two different name server from two different providers for my `example.org` domain:

```
example.org NS ns.example.com
example.org NS ns.example.net
```

But I have put an A record only on the second one:

```
ns.example.com:
    ---

ns.example.net:    
    site.example.org A 198.51.100.1
```

What will happen when users will try to reach `site.example.org`? Will they randomly fail to resolve the name or will all of them be able to connect?

Comment: Do the nameservers on both `ns.example.net` and `ns.example.com` think they are authoritative for the `example.org` zone?  Or does `ns.example.com` simply not know about the zone at all?

Comment: @MadHatter Thanks for the edits. They both know about the `example.org`. I am thinking about the scenario where the control panel of `ns.example.com` is temporarily not accessible but I still need to add a functioning `A` record.

Comment: Sorry, are you keeping your namservers in sync **manually**?

Comment: @MadHatter No :-) But the provider's management web service occasionally goes offline. I want to understand if in this case I still can set the record for `site.example.org` at another name server.

Comment: It depends on what the provider's doing under the hood.  If the second provider is really running a slave nameserver for your zone, it won't *let* you set a record.  I think the real solution to your problems is to get a better DNS provider.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If one of the authoritative name servers isn't responding, the recursive name server tries another. However, if it can reach a name server that responds with a `NXDOMAIN`, it will stop and the result will be that there's no such hostname. Due to *Negative Caching of DNS Queries* ([RFC2308](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2308)) this will last for the *time-to-live* (TTL), not just until requested again. What you suggest wouldn't work!

There is only one correct solution to this: you only configure the records on the provider that handles your **primary** authoritative DNS server. The other server must be configured as a **secondary** authoritative DNS server. The primary server notifies the secondaries it's aware of, and the secondary servers requests for a DNS Zone Transfer (`AXFR`) containing the entire zone.

During the zone transfer there's no management web services involved, so it doesn't matter if it's down on the secondary service, as long as you don't need to change the name servers.

Generally it's not a good idea to use different providers for authoritative name servers although *network diversity* is [required](https://www.iana.org/help/nameserver-requirements). That's because for the zone transfer the secondary server needs special permissions, and service providers with web control panels may not have considered that. Also, any decent service provider should be able to arrange you a secondary DNS server that meet all the requirements. Those servers are configured to co-operate flawlessly.